# Record camera pose at each frame of animation

Tags: python, animation, camera

I created a Bezier curve, my camera is following that curve, tracking an object and thus rendering it from different angles. While running this animation, I also want to print/record the camera pose using Python. I can start the animation in Python using:

```
import bpy
bpy.ops.screen.animation_play()
```

But how can I get `cam.location` for each animation frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import bpy

def handler(scene):
    print("Frame Change", scene.frame_current)
    print("Camera location", scene.camera.location)
    
bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre.append(handler)

bpy.ops.screen.animation_play()
```

Will print the frame number and camera location at each frame.

This works because you can write a handler that is invoked each time the frame number changes.  In this case, the handler runs *before* the frame is displayed or rendered.  See [this page of the manual](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.app.handlers.html#bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre) for details.

This will print to the system console, and it will do so every time the frame is changed, including when you manually scrub the timeline cursor.